# compare two values in ranorex

Tags: compare, ranorex

We are using Ranorex 5.02 We need to compare values (numbers) in website UI and generated pdf file these values always are the same. Each time the system will generate new values for UI and pdf file. We need to check that the new generated values are correct. 
Adding validation methods not really help because the system recorded actual number and after running test script again validation is failed. We tried to create variables in validations the system displays unbounded variable message.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Get Value" action in order to store the values into a variable. After that you can compare the values using the "Equals" method from the [String class in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image]

```
 public void CompareText(string webText, string pdfText)
    {
        if(webText.Equals(pdfText))
        {
            Report.Info("Text is equal!");
        }
        else
        {
            Report.Info("Text is NOT equal!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would actually recommend using Report.Failure in the else block, but otherwise this answer is a good one.  You could also use the validation methods with the two variables if you don't want to use usercode, or the ranorex library function that accomplishes the same thing located here http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/M_Ranorex_Validate_AreEqual_2.htm