# Take a snapshot of program after every test

Tags: screenshot, ranorex

I have a test setup that opens a program and does a test on loop.

I want to have the program take a snapshot / screenshot of the program (only) after a test, inside the loop.

Is this possible?

Below is my test suite run:

[image: Ranorex Test Suite]

So it is fine, and I can run through the full test, but I can't see the results, unless I have Ranorex open. This is not sufficient, if I run this on another PC or VM.

*NOTE: All the blanked out boxes, are my variables.*

Comment: I have gone a different route, and tried to compare an Expected Result to the Result that the program is generating. This post has helped me too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410655/compare-two-values-in-ranorex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take a screenshot of the app under test, 3 simple steps:

1. Create a repo item of the application (using Ranorex Spy).
2. Drag n Drop the repo item in a recording.
3. Select the "Capture Screenshot" action.

Hope this helps (even though you have solved the issue!)

Comment: How do you write the screenshot to a folder? I have a `$varScreenshotPath` variable. So basically it is "Report | Screenshot | varScreenshotPath | Info | {windowName}"

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are trying to achieve. Usually, screenshots are captured to facilitate troubleshooting the test execution when a failure occured while the test ran unattended. Having them in the report should be sufficient.  In the meanwhile, you can take a look at this Ranorex class which has a Screenshot property: https://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/?topic=html/T_Ranorex_Core_ElementInfo.htm. Maybe this can help...

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification.

Ranorex Support team helped me by giving me some C# code to help save screenshots to a location on my PC.

Add a Code Module to the Action Screen, then add the following code:

```
    public void SaveScreenshot(string savelocation)
    {
            //Take a screenshot of a specific element
            Bitmap image = Imaging.CaptureImageAuto(repo.program.SSTabCtlWndClass);

            //Name and path to store the screenshot
            String imageName = String.Format(varNumber1 + "_" + varNumber2 + ".jpg");
            String pathImageName = Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\Screenshots\", imageName);

            //Save the screenhot in your specific folder
            image.Save(pathImageName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```